# Simplified the series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, (n+a)^{^\alpha}\, L^{(1)}_{n}(a)$?

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

Any reference that we can find the following series expansion 
$$f_{\alpha}(a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, (n+a)^{^\alpha}\,  L^{(1)}_{n}(a),$$
where $a>0, \alpha>0$ and $L^{(1)}_{n}(.)$ are the generalized Laguerre polynomials.

Thanks

Comment: Formally, at least for positive integer exponents $\alpha$, your series is what you get starting from the generating series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  t^n L^{(1)}_n(a)=  \frac{1}{(1-t)^{2}} e^{-\frac{ta}{1-t}}$$
multiplying it by $t^a$, applying $(t\partial_t)^\alpha$ and evaluating for $t=1$. I'm not sure positive integer $\alpha$ produce convergent series, though.

Comment: Ok. But it is difficult to derivative with respect to $\alpha$, because $\alpha$ is a real number >0?

Comment: I guess for noninteger $\alpha$ one could use fractional derivatives and $(t\partial_t)^\alpha=t(\partial_t)^\alpha+ \partial_t^{\alpha-1}$.